# Batch file finding strings for Current network SSID

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, txt, netsh

I need to assign the current network/wifi SSID to an environment variable in a batch file (`set "var=x`) to then use it. My script saves a file with the SSID, but it's the entire lines, i need the variable to only be the SSID value.
Here is my code:

```
@echo off
set "npcm=%appdata%\npcm.txt"
2>NUL netsh wlan show interfaces | findstr /i "SSID" > "%npcm%"
pause
```

The output file is:

```
    SSID                   : MyNetwork
    BSSID                  : xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I tried using the following lines of code but it doesn't work, also the %a was %%a but after some researches i found out i need 1 % only.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims='" %a in ('type file.h ^|find "#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_"') do set "var=!var!%a"
```

Comment: Which current network? A computer can have multiple network interface connections, both wired and wireless.

Comment: The command line for usage in a __batch file__: `set "SSID=" & for /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %%H in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe wlan show interfaces 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "\<SSID\>"') do set "SSID=%%I"` The same command line for usage directly in a __command prompt window__: `set "SSID=" & for /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %H in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe wlan show interfaces 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "\<SSID\>"') do @set "SSID=%I"` `SSID` is undefined on no WLAN interface with an SSID available at all.

Comment: I might also suggest a modification to the above `for` loop example: ```@Set "SSID=" & For /F "Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Show Interfaces 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RC:"  *SSID  *: [^ ]"') Do @Set "SSID=%%H"``` This is just a small change to match only lines containing a SSID with at least one non space character.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the last advice, btw I was working on wireless network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line for usage in a batch file: `set "SSID=" & for /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %%H in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe wlan show interfaces 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "\<SSID\>"') do set "SSID=%%I"` The same command line for usage directly in a command prompt window: `set "SSID=" & for /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %H in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe wlan show interfaces 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "\<SSID\>"') do @set "SSID=%I"` `SSID` is undefined on no WLAN interface with an SSID available at all.

– Mofi

This was in the comments